# Multiple caches not workig in Spring EhCache

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

In my code, I have added EhCache with Spring MVC. I have declared two cache names, where one cache is working but another is not working. I have attached my ehcache.xml here

```
<defaultCache eternal="false" 
    maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="600" 
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

<cache name="pp" eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="500" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600" timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

<cache name="cc" eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="500" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600" timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

Here are my java code :

```
@Cacheable(value="pp")
public Result getPlayers() throws Exception {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(PLAYERS_URL);
    LOGGER.info("PLAYERS_URL {}", URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
    Result result = omapper.readValue(response, Result.class);
    return result;
}
```

Only cc is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by implying that "pp is not working"? Hard to provide any useful advice with the limited description.

Comment: Thanks for replying, hope we will solve this issue asap. PP is cache name, I have two different caches (cc and pp). cc is used to cache json data from one url where pp is used to cache json data from another url. You can check my ehcache.xml posted above.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of comment you expect. Issue does not seem to be in configuration. Again, what do you mean it is "not working"? How are you using these caches? Can you post other configuration files that are relevant, like the SpringMVC one, or code snippets, logs, etc ...

Comment: HI Louis. I was checking the code and found that there are issues with duplicate keys. I am using default key generation. Should I implement custom key generator, that will take care of it. My method name and parameters should be used to generate the keys, even when there are not parameters then also it should generate a unique key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to trace the root cause of it and fixed this issue. The method that I declared as @Cacheable, has some local calls, means one mehtod in the same service class was calling it. When I removed the call from local class then it worked fine. This may be useful for others.

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: Could not follow what you mean when you said "The method that I declared as @Cacheable, has some local calls, means one mehtod in the same service class was calling it. "